# Using localstorage to create a favorites list

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am a novice at `javascript`, and normally just search the internet for code and adjust it so it does what I want it to do. In the process I do learn a bit about coding.
However I cannot seem to find (or understand what i have found) a way to create a favorites page with links to articles (Html-pages) using *localstorage*.

I have a local website with about 4000 `html` pages. I want to add a button on each page and when you click it, it needs to store the page `url` and title to a *localstorage* list in the following format:

```
 <html>
     <head>
         <title>Favorites</title>
         <font size="5">
         <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
     </head>
     <body>
         <div class="content">
             <div class="wrap">
                 <div class="content-grid">
                 </div>
                 <div class="grid">
                     <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="" /></a>
                 </div>
                 <div class="favorites">
                     <h1>Favorites</h1>
                     <hr>
                     <a href="page1.html">title 1</a> <hr>
                     <a href="page2.html">title 2</a> <hr>
                     <a href="page3.html">title 3</a> <hr>
                 </div>
 </html>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you needing help with the localStorage side, building the favorites page programmatically, or adding the favorites button?

Comment: You really should look at using a CMS like Wordpress or Joomla to do what you're doing. Also, Learning PHP probably wouldn't go amiss either...

Comment: @ Mordred, The localstorage side, i'm currently trying to incorperate a dropdownmenu to the article pages to add the page to a localstorage favoriteslist. For now that part is going okey.

Comment: @ Sparatan117, I can only use HTML5, Javascript and CSS since i'm planning on converting the website to an android app using Phonegap Build.

Answer (score 1):

[Local Storage and how to use it](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/)